# Const array using data from two objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript

I require some help on this particular issue I'm encountering, I'm trying to const an array using two objects with `Object.keys(...).map` and `&&`.

Code:

```
const plugins: PluginManifest[] = Object.values(window.Aliucord.pluginManager.plugins).map((p) => p.manifest) && Object.values(window.Aliucord.pluginManager.disabledPlugins).map(p => p);
```

The above code uses the data only from the `disabledPlugins` Object.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would expect `&&` to simply be resolving to the second part of its expression.  `&&` certainly doesn't *combine arrays*.  But you can combine them into one array by spreading them into an array literal.  For example:

```js
const firstArray = [1,2,3];
const secondArray = [4,5,6];
const finalArray = [...firstArray, ...secondArray];
console.log(finalArray);
```

So in your case, since those `.map()` operations produce arrays, you can spread them into another array:

```
const plugins: PluginManifest[] = [
  ...Object.values(window.Aliucord.pluginManager.plugins).map((p) => p.manifest),
  ...Object.values(window.Aliucord.pluginManager.disabledPlugins).map(p => p)
];
```